# How do I display a specific post in Jekyll?

Tags: github, content-management-system, yaml, jekyll

I'm wanting to use `Jekyll` as a CMS essentially, so I would like to take the content from a post and display it in a specific area of my website.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {{ post.content }}
 {% endfor %}
```

This displays all of the content from all of the posts, however I'd like to take content from one post at a time. I'm fairly new to Jekyll, so I'm not sure if i'm supposed to add `YAML` front matter into my posts and target them with a "for post in site with `title_____"` post.content" of sorts.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

```html
{% assign thepost = site.posts | where:"slug","post_slug" %}
{% for post in thepost %}
 {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

And on the post;

`slug: post_slug`

Comment: Thank you. You can use `title` as well. It works.

Answer (score 2):

**I figured it out, sorry I posted prematurely.**

The answer is add a category to your post with YAML front matter and then in your include file use:

```
{% for post in site.categories.CATEGORYNAMEHERE %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This won't work if you want to display only a single post.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Jekyll 4.1.0, you can use [`find`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#find):

```
{{ site.posts | find: "title", "The Post Title" }}
```